# jQuery - Appending a div to body, the body is the object?

Tags: jquery, html, append

When I'm adding a div to body, it's returning the body as the object and then whenever I use that - it's obviously using body. Bad.

Code:-

```
var holdyDiv = $('body').append('div');
$(holdyDiv).attr('id', 'holdy');
```

The 'id' of holdy is now being added to body... eh? What am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

jQuery methods returns the set they were applied on.

Use [.appendTo](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/):

```
var $div = $('<div />').appendTo('body');
$div.attr('id', 'holdy');
```

Comment: That seems to add it in the right place but return every object? as when I set the holdyDiv id it has changed every id to holdDiv.

Comment: It will return the DIV element just appended and apply the id to this element only.

Answer (score 22):

```
    $('body').append($('<div/>', {
        id: 'holdy' 
    }));
```

Answer (score 11):

```
$('</div>').attr('id', 'holdy').appendTo('body');
```

Answer (score 8):

Instead use use `appendTo`. `append` or `appendTo` returns a jQuery object so you don't have to wrap it inside `$()`.

```
var holdyDiv = $('<div />').appendTo('body');
holdyDiv.attr('id', 'holdy');
```

`.appendTo()` reference: http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/

Alernatively you can try this also.

```
$('<div />', { id: 'holdy' }).appendTo('body');
               ^
             (Here you can specify any attribute/value pair you want)
```

Comment: `var holdyDiv = $('div').appendTo('body');` should be `var holdyDiv = $('<div />').appendTo('body');`. Note change: `'div'` --> `'<div />'`. As written in the answer, the 'holdy' id will incorrectly be applied to all pre-existing divs, not just one newly created div.

Answer (score 6):

Using jQuery [appendTo](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) try this:

```
var holdyDiv = $('<div></div>').attr('id', 'holdy');
holdyDiv.appendTo('body');
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var $div = $('<div />').appendTo('body');
$div.attr('id', 'holdy');
```

Comment: This answer currently has 2 downvotes. I suspect 2 reasons (1) it is only code (valid but mild criticism); (2) it is identical to the accepted answer (currently 35 upvotes). However the edit history shows this answer actually made a small but very important correction to the accepted answer. Original accepted answer: `var $div=$('div')...` referring incorrectly to all pre-existing divs. This correction: `var $div=$('<div/>`)...` referring correctly to single newly created div. The accepted answer was subsequently edited. Kudos to @Abhishek. (Some other answers also caught this.)